# Estou com problemas ao criar um Chatbot em Python

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

chatbot = ChatBot('HiAsda')

#Cria um novo treinador para o bot
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

#Treina o chatbot baseado no corpus
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.portuguese.greetings")
#obtem uma resposta a uma declaração de entrada
chatbot.get_response("Olá, como você está? ")
```

Retorna

```
"C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\Scripts\python.exe" "C:/Users/Familia Pantoja/chatterbot01/Programa/__init__.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Familia Pantoja/chatterbot01/Programa/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tagging import PosHypernymTagger
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tokenizers import get_sentence_tokenizer
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tokenizers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.corpus import load_corpus, list_corpus_files
  File "C:\Users\Familia Pantoja\chatterbot01\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from chatterbot_corpus.corpus import DATA_DIRECTORY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Podem me orientar? Sou novo em programação e novo em python

Comment: A aplicação depende de um módulo que não está instalado. *ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'*. Basta instalá-lo.

Answer (score 1):

Olá!
Também sou novo com python, estou fazendo um "curso" para criar um chatbot e usa-lo no whatsapp...
...bom, eu também obtive este mesmo erro e procurando por ai afora,
rodei este comando dentra da pasta onde esta instalado o Anaconda3

**conda uninstall PyYAML**

diversos pacotes foram atualizados e tambem alguns foram removidos.
Terminado o processo, rodei o comando

**pip install chatterbot_corpus**

Foi instalado, porém esta solicitando novos pacotes no qual estou instalando.

Resumindo, com o comando do "conda uninstall" consegui fazer o downgrade do PyYAML e com isso seguir o "enterro"...

Espero que funcione para você.
Abraços e sucesso no projeto!