# Módulo chatterbot_corpus não encontrado após instalar chatterbot

Tags: python, chatterbot

Alguem sabe o que pode ser esses erros?

```
C:\Python37_64\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Python37_64/chat.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Python37_64/chat.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.trainers import ListTrainer
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tagging import PosHypernymTagger
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tokenizers import get_sentence_tokenizer
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tokenizers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.corpus import load_corpus, list_corpus_files
  File "C:\Python37_64\venv\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from chatterbot_corpus.corpus import DATA_DIRECTORY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'
```

Comment: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/377449/5878

Answer (score 0):

O erro diz que o módulo `chatterbot_corpus` não está instalado. Tente atualizar o `chatterbot`:

```
pip install --upgrade chatterbot
```

Ou instalar o `chatterbot_corpus` individualmente:

```
pip install --upgrade chatterbot_corpus
```

Obs: se for `python3`, o certo é `pip3`

Comment: Recomenda-se executar, ao invés de `pip`, o comando `python3 -m pip`, pois assim fica explícito no comando a versão utilizada, mas mais indicado ainda é utilizar virtualenvs.

Comment: tento o upgrade e mesmo assim o erro continua, muito estranho isso

Comment: Da uma olhada aqui: https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/826

Comment: c:\teste>pip freeze
blis==0.2.4
certifi==2019.3.9
chardet==3.0.4
ChatterBot==1.0.5
chatterbot-corpus==1.2.0
cymem==2.0.2