# Erro com Import em Python

Tags: python, chatbot, chatterbot

Estou tentando criar um Bot em Python:

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from chatterbot.trainer import ListTrainer # trainador
from chatterbot import ChatBot # chatbot
import os

bot = ChatBot('Teste')

bot.set_trainer(ListTrainer)

for arq in os.listdir('arq'):
    chats = open('arq/' + arq, 'r').readlines()
    bot.train(chats)

while True:
    resq = input('Você: ')

    resp = bot.get_response(resq)
    print('Bot: '+resp)
```

Sempre aparece a mensagem:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/danie/Desktop/chatBot/main.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.trainer import ListTrainer # trainador
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .chatterbot import ChatBot
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\chatterbot.py", line 2, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from chatterbot.storage.storage_adapter import StorageAdapter
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\storage\storage_adapter.py", line 3, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tagging import PosHypernymTagger
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tagging.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.tokenizers import get_sentence_tokenizer
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\tokenizers.py", line 4, in <module>
    from chatterbot.corpus import load_corpus, list_corpus_files
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\site-packages\chatterbot\corpus.py", line 5, in <module>
    from chatterbot_corpus.corpus import DATA_DIRECTORY
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'chatterbot_corpus'
```

Comment: Reorganize a sua pergunta, poste o código completo e utilize as marcações de código neles para melhor visualização.

Comment: Apesar de a questão também não estar resolvida, é uma possível duplicada de https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/382386/m%c3%b3dulo-chatterbot-corpus-n%c3%a3o-encontrado-ap%c3%b3s-instalar-chatterbot. Parece que o único site que vi alguém saindo feliz com o resultado foi no [GitHub](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot/issues/1708)

Comment: Versão diferente de chatterbot... set_trainer() nem existe mais eu acho..